# Randomize and Limit ngFor List Items on HTML

Tags: html, angular, rxjs

I have a large JSON file and am trying to randomize and limit the ones that are shown to a list item on HTML. The file has more than 100 items but I would like to show only ten at a time.
I understand doing this by pagination on the server side would be better but this project is to be used locally and for learning purposes only.

This is a project based [on this repository](https://github.com/johnpapa/heroes-angular). It is basically the same but I would like handle more items by paginating it on the client side(`hero-list.component.html`). It would be worth checking it out. Otherwise I will paste below the important part.

Can someone help me?

hero.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  EntityCollectionServiceBase,
  EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory
} from '@ngrx/data';
import { Hero } from '../core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeroService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Hero> {
  constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
    super('Hero', serviceElementsFactory);
  }
}
```

hero-list.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy
} from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-list',
  templateUrl: './hero-list.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HeroListComponent {
  @Input() heroes: Hero[];
  @Output() deleted = new EventEmitter<Hero>();
  @Output() selected = new EventEmitter<Hero>();

  selectHero(hero: Hero) {
    this.selected.emit(hero);
  }

  deleteHero(hero: Hero) {
    this.deleted.emit(hero);
  }

  // trackByHero(hero: Hero): string {
  //   return hero.id;
  // }

  trackByHero(_ /* index not used */: number, hero: Hero): string {
    return hero.id;
  }
}
```

hero-list.component.html

```
<ul class="list">
  <li
    *ngFor="let hero of heroes; trackBy: trackByHero; let i = index"
    role="presentation"
  >
    <div class="card">
      <app-card-content
        [name]="hero.name"
        [description]="hero.description"
      ></app-card-content>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <app-button-footer
          class="card-footer-item"
          [className]="'delete-item'"
          [iconClasses]="'fas fa-trash'"
          (clicked)="deleteHero($event)"
          label="Delete"
          [item]="hero"
        ></app-button-footer>
        <app-button-footer
          class="card-footer-item"
          [className]="'edit-item'"
          [iconClasses]="'fas fa-edit'"
          (clicked)="selectHero($event)"
          label="Edit"
          [item]="hero"
        ></app-button-footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

db.json:

```
    {
  "heroes": [
    {
      "id": "HeroAslaug",
      "name": "Aslaug",
      "description": "warrior queen"
    },
    {
      "id": "HeroBjorn",
      "name": "Bjorn Ironside",
      "description": "king of 9th century Sweden"
    },
    {
      "id": "HeroIvar",
      "name": "Ivar the Boneless",
      "description": "commander of the Great Heathen Army"
    },
    {
      "id": "HeroLagertha",
      "name": "Lagertha the Shieldmaiden",
      "description": "aka Hlaðgerðr"
    },
    {
      "id": "HeroRagnar",
      "name": "Ragnar Lothbrok",
      "description": "aka Ragnar Sigurdsson"
    },
    {
      "id": "HeroThora",
      "name": "Thora Town-hart",
      "description": "daughter of Earl Herrauðr of Götaland"
    }
  ]
}
```

Appreciate it!

Comment: Is you mean load n number of array object when you do pagination in locally?

Comment: Yes @ArunkumarRamasamy . Load n number of array objects randomly.

Comment: you need randomly or index based?

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy Randomly based. 10 heroes randomly shown.

Answer (score 0):

A "pagination" if you has all the elements in an array is simply use [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

You has two variables

```
page:number=0 //the first page is 0
pageSize:number=10

<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes|slice:(page*pageSize):(page+1)*pageSize;
     let i = index">
  ...
</li>
```

To randomize an array simply use

```
   arrayRandom=this.heroes.map(x=>({ord:Math.random(),data:x}))
                          .sort((a,b)=>a.ord>b.ord?1:a.ord<b.ord?-1:0)
                          .map(x=>x.data)
```